# Should I call async function from await_suspend

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

Given a function that receives a continuation callback

```cpp
void async_write(string_view buffer, function<void(error_code)> callback);
```

where such callback might be called from a different thread,
is the only and the best option to wrap such function in a closure and call it from `await_suspend` ?

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct Awaitable {
  F f;
  std::coroutine_handle<> resume;
  error_code result;
  
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> resume) {
    this->resume = resume;
    f([this](error_code result) {
      this->result = result;
      this->resume();
    });
  }
};

// Usage
auto result = co_await Awaitable{[&](auto callback) {
  async_write(buffer, callback);
}};
```

If we call `async_write` before `await_suspend`, we'd have to pass it a temporary callback that might be executed in-parallel with `await_suspend`, thus requiring a costly synchronization (e.g. `atomic_flag`).

Boost.Asio uses similar callables to implement their `async_*` functions, however such approach looks quite uncanny, hence the question. Maybe there is another way to use functions with callbacks in coroutines.

Comment: An atomic flag is "costly synchronization" now?

Comment: await_suspend is good place to store coroutine_handle to resume it "later". You can make some tricks with await_transform to get coroutine_handle earlier - but it has no sense when you want to resume it - you cannot resume something that is not suspended.

Comment: @NicolBolas The synchronization is costly, so the atomic too - but it can be the least costly way of synchronization, especially if you care about applying the best std::memory_order for your case.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's more costly than a closure with no synchronization at all.

Comment: @Abyx: Without synchronization, you can't have threaded, asynchronous processing and communication.